# RegEx for specific pattern, excluding URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

Long story, but I need to take some fakey-HTML and replace it with real HTML using JavaScript. For example:

```
{span class:text-bold data:attribute}TITLE{/span}
```

Needs to change into:

```
<span class="text-bold" data="attribute">TITLE</span>
```

I'm using RegEx to do this as I can't possibly anticipate every attribute that could be placed on every element. The expression that is more or less working to find every instance of data:attribute:

```
/(\w+\:)(.[^\s\}]*)/g
```

However, there is an issue; this expression also matches URLs, for example:

```
http://www.google.ca
```

In an attempt to exclude any URLs from matching, I changed the expression like so:

```
/(?!http)(\w+\:)(.[^\s\}]*)/g
```

However, this did not have the expected effect, the pattern continues to match URLs, just without the leading 'h'. For example,

```
ttp://www.google.ca
```

I'll admit I haven't used RegEx in quite a while, so I'm probably misunderstanding something. How can I tell a RegEx pattern to NOT match any match that begins with a specific set of characters?

Comment: add the complete code (include the replace).

Comment: Why doesn't your regex match the `{}` around your data? Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Add a word-boundary before `\w+` => `\b\w+`. Also no need to escape `:` and `}`

Comment: Or better, put it before the lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negated look-ahead right before the possible `//`, i.e. after the colon.

```
"foo://bar".match(/(\w+:)(?!\/\/)([^\s\}]*)/); //no dice
"foo:bar".match(/(\w+:)(?!\/\/)([^\s\}]*)/); //dice
```

Of course, this will also block any attribute values that legitimately begin with `//`, but I assume that's a risk worth taking.

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you! I guess I was silly for trying to match the http instead of the //.

Comment: Made a small change: /(\w+)(?::)(?!\/\/)([^\s}]*)/  This way, the colon separating the attribute and the data isn't captured.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with a regex nested in the handler-function of a regex-replace:

```js
document.getElementById('outp').value = document.getElementById('inp').value.replace(
    /{([^}]+)}/g, function(m, tag) {
        return '<' + tag.replace(/(\w+):(\S+)/g, '$1="$2"') + '>';
    });
```

```css
textarea {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inp" rows="5">{span class:text-bold data:attribute}TITLE{/span}

http://www.google.ca</textarea>
<textarea id="outp" rows="5"></textarea>
```

The first regex `{([^}]+)}` grabs all instances between `{` and `}` and the function inside that only works with those matches so any other colons remain untouched.